# Request getting read timed out from code using resttemplate. But same request goes through in postman

Tags: java, rest, web-services, resttemplate

This is a large request. But it works in postman and returns after a min.
The rest template timeout has been set as 5min. Both read and connection timeout. Somehow this works for smaller requests. I also debugged and I could see the timeout setting being applied.

However the order went through and reached our target system and order got placed there. But we never get a response back, hence our system shows order failed since no response was received. The same works through postman. I checked through the headers, everything is ditto same

```
final String responseStr = restTemplate.postForObject(url, httpEntity, String.class);
```

```
<alias name="defaultSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory" alias="simpleClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
<bean id="defaultSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory" scope="prototype">
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="${connection.timeout}"/>
    <property name="readTimeout" value="${read.timeout}"/>
</bean>
```

As per best practices, we must use a rest template creator. **But is this issue caused by this**? This is all existing code. Is it worth the refactor? Because we had already tried some options(**bufferRequestBody** to false) which has led to other strange issues. It works in local, but not in higher env as well

Or is it caused by **not using custom message converters**? Should we take this direction? Something like below since we are using json string request

```
<property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                            <constructor-arg value="application"/>
                            <constructor-arg value="json"/>
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                            <constructor-arg value="application"/>
                            <constructor-arg value="octet-stream"/>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Or should is this caused by **request interceptor**?

Or by **Error handler**? I debugged this flow to see where exactly it read times out. And I could see execute method is happening fine, but then later in error handler.

```
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler

@Override
      public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
            int rawStatusCode = response.getRawStatusCode();
            HttpStatus statusCode = HttpStatus.resolve(rawStatusCode);
            return (statusCode != null ? hasError(statusCode) : hasError(rawStatusCode));
      }
```

It times out at **response.getRawStatusCode()**

Has anyone faced something like this with rest template? Please share or suggest. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What exception actually gets thrown?

Comment: SocketException - Read Timed out

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is because of Windows update. I need to update Windows, restart the PC, then it works. But I'm don't know the root cause.